# resample in pandas with the method in a variable

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, resampling

Pandas changed its resample API on version 18.1. The reduction methods are no longer a argument to the resample method, but they are their own methods.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=100, freq='S')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 500, len(rng)), index=rng)

#Old API
ts.resample('5Min', how='sum')

#New API
ts.resample('5Min').sum()
```

I had some code that acted like this:

```
def my_func(my_series, how="sum"):
    #Do some stuff before
    my_series.resample('5Min' how=how)
```

How do I make this with the new API? I want `my_func` to be able to call the resample method with different reduction methods.

One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38585774/1952996) already covers the case when the "how" is a just an aggregation function. I had more in mind cases where we want to perform upsampling.

E.g:

```
#Old API:
ts.resample('250L', fill_method='ffill')
#New API
ts.resample('250L').ffill()
```

Note that on my real code I have something more close to this:

```
def my_func(dummy_df, freq="10Min", how="last", label="right", closed="right", fill_method="ffill"):
    dummy_df.resample(freq, how=how, label=label, closed=closed, fill_method=fill_method)
```

and want to write it again with the new API.

Confusingly the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) still (26.07.2016) has this line:

> Any function available via dispatching can be given to the how parameter by name, including sum, mean, std, sem, max, min, median, first, last, ohlc.

But the `how` parameter is supposed to become deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segregate `how` and `fill_method` and pass them through `getattr`:

```
def my_func(dummy_df, freq="10Min", how="last",
            label="right", closed="right", fill_method="ffill"):
    resample = dummy_df.resample(freq, label=label, closed=closed)
    return getattr(getattr(resample, how)(), fill_method)()
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution with [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html):

```
print (ts.resample('5Min').agg('sum'))
```

---

```
print (ts.resample('5Min').sum())
2012-01-01    24223
Freq: 5T, dtype: int32

print (ts.resample('5Min').agg('sum'))
2012-01-01    24223
Freq: 5T, dtype: int32
```

So custom function is:

```
def my_func(my_series, how="sum"):
    #Do some stuff before
    return my_series.resample('5Min').agg(how)

print (my_func(ts))
2012-01-01    24223
Freq: 5T, dtype: int32
```

Comment: very simple and elegant!